# Preserve orphans, NHibernate one-to-many

Tags: nhibernate

I'm successfully using a one-to-many relationship in NHibernate apart from one thing. When I remove a child record from the collection held in the parent, I don't want it to delete the child record. I just want it to blank out the foreign key in the child record.

This is so that I can reattach the child record to a different parent later on.

Is this possible? I have tried various cascade options but they all seem to delete the child when I call Remove() on the collection.

Here's my parent mapping (a 'SectionItem')

```
  <class name="Munch.Domain.MenuSection, Munch.Dao" table="menu_section">
    <id name="Id" type="Int32">
      <generator class="native" />
    </id>
    <property name="Position" />
    <property name="Title" />
    <property name="Description" />
    <bag name="MenuItems" cascade="save-update">
      <key column="menuSectionId"/>
      <one-to-many class="MenuItem"/>
    </bag>    
  </class>
```

Child object (a 'MenuItem')

```
  <class name="Munch.Domain.MenuItem, Munch.Dao" table="menu_item">
    <id name="Id" type="Int32">
      <generator class="native" />
    </id>
    <property name="Title" />
    <property name="Description" />
    <property name="Type" />
    <property name="Image" />
  </class>
```

And here is a test that builds up the child collection and saves the parent/children in one go. Then I remove one child (making a note of it's id before I do) and then I try to retrieve the 'removed' child to check that it is still in the database. I would expect it to be there, but with a null foreign key back to the parent.

```
    // Create the menu section
    MenuSection ms = new MenuSection();
    ms.Title = "MenuSectionTitle";
    ms.Description = "Description";
    ms = menuSectionDao.Save(ms);

    // Create a couple of menu items
    MenuItem item1 = new MenuItem();
    item1.Title = "AAA";
    item1.Description = "AAA Desc";

    MenuItem item2 = new MenuItem();
    item2.Title = "BBB";
    item2.Description = "BBB Desc";

    List<MenuItem> items = new List<MenuItem>();
    items.Add(item1);
    items.Add(item2);

    // Add the items to the menu section
    ms.MenuItems = items;

    // Save it and check
    menuSectionDao.Save(ms);
    Assert.IsNotNull(ms, "Menu Section wasn't saved");
    Assert.True(ms.Id > 0, "Menu Section id is not greater than zero, probably an error");

    log.Debug("MenuSection saved with id " + ms.Id);

    // See what's been saved
    MenuSection ms2 = menuSectionDao.Find(ms.Id);
    Assert.IsNotNull(ms2, "Retrieved a null value");

    // Check that the menu items were saved too
    Assert.IsNotNull(ms2.MenuItems);
    Assert.IsTrue(ms2.MenuItems.Count == 2);
    Assert.AreEqual(ms2.MenuItems[0].Title, "AAA");
    Assert.AreEqual(ms2.MenuItems[1].Title, "BBB"); 

    // Try and remove the item
    int item1Id = ms2.MenuItems[0].Id;

    log.Debug("Deleting item 0 with id " + item1Id);
    ms2.MenuItems.RemoveAt(0);
    menuSectionDao.Save(ms2);

    MenuSection ms3 = menuSectionDao.Find(ms.Id);
    Assert.IsTrue(ms3.MenuItems.Count == 1);

    // Check we haven't deleted the menu item
    MenuItem item = menuItemDao.Find(item1Id);
    Assert.IsNotNull(item);
}
```

(the test is failing on the last line by the way)

Thanks

Comment: Could you post the relevant mappings?

Comment: Yep I have added them to the initial post. Thanks for taking a look, appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

The only cascade option that deletes entities that are removed from a collection is "all-delete-orphan". So it must be something in your code that deletes the entities.

Also, make sure to set the parent reference to null when you remove an entity from the collection. NHibernate won't do this for you.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. About to start working on it again so I will bear in mind what you said and see how I get on.

Comment: Sorry I'm still missing something basic. I didn't have a reference to the parent from the child, so I added a many-to-one mapping like this 

<many-to-one name="MenuSection" ... not-null="false" />. 

Then I removed the child from the collection, and set the parent reference to null:

IEnumerator childEnumerator = ms2.MenuItems.GetEnumerator();
childEnumerator.MoveNext();
MenuItem mi = (MenuItem)childEnumerator.Current;
mi.MenuSection = null;
ms2.MenuItems.Remove(mi);
menuSectionDao.Save(ms2);

When I retrieve all children though, it's gone, help!

Comment: PS I should add that I am retrieving the children through their own DAO just to be sure

Comment: @Richard I don't know how NHibernate handles orphans in unidirectional collections. But have you added the inverse="true" attribute to your bag when you tested the bidirectional one?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand why, but I got it working in the end so thanks to everyone who has helped me.

It turns out I didn't need to many-to-one in the child, and I didn't need inverse='true' for my particular case. All I needed to do was save the child individually (using it's own DAO) just before removing it from the parent's collection.

```
    IEnumerator childEnumerator = ms2.MenuItems.GetEnumerator(); 
    childEnumerator.MoveNext(); 
    MenuItem mi = (MenuItem)childEnumerator.Current; 

    menuItemDao.Save(mi);  // This is the line I needed

    ms2.MenuItems.Remove(mi); 
    menuSectionDao.Save(ms2);
```

When I save my child (mi), as far as it's concerned, it's still related to the parent at that point. I'm sure it's got something to do with Flushing but if anyone can explain clearly why this was necessary please do!